# Flutter Android Intent and WhatsApp

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, contacts, whatsapp

I am creating a contacts application and I would like to be able to add buttons to make video calls and WhatsApp calls. To get the contacts I use flutter_contacts and with this I get a Contact object that has an accounts property (WhatsApp, Telegram...). To perform the intent I am using android_intent_plus but I don't know how to make it work correctly.

```
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: "action_view",
    data: "content://com.android.contacts/data/${contact.id}",
    type: "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.voip.call",
    package: "com.whatsapp"
);
```

[image]